# How to programatically trigger a Liquibase migration?

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I'm currently running Liquibase migrations on the startup of my Spring Boot app. I'd like to separate application of one of my migrations from the deployment. The migrations contains creation of the foreign constraints and I'd like to apply it only after the data migration is complete. I know I can use preconditions to prevent schema migrations to be run initially. I can than perform the data migration and fulfil whatever precondition I've specified. How can I now trigger another attempt at applying the migrations without redeploying/restarting the apps? Servlet listener sounds promising, but the documentation for it is currently broken

Comment: Take a look into `SpringLiquibase` and method `afterPropertiesSet`

Comment: This seems pretty low level and would mean copy&pasting significant chunks of that class. Does it mean triggering migrations is not something Liquibase provides via some kind of API?

Comment: Looks like a good pointer in either case!